# Capturing individual cells of a p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Is there a way I can capture the value of individual cells in a JSF datatable based upon the user click ?

So I have a table as shown in the below image and I want to create a string by combining different cells from each column which the user selects. From each column the user can click on one or more cells and the value in the cells will be updated (*appended*) in the textarea.

[image: How the datatable looks like]

Below is the output that I want to capture in a textbox.

[image: desired outocme]

What is the best and the most efficient way to achieve this is JSF. Doesn't have to be a datatable but i hope you know what I want to achieve here.

Comment: Maybe https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/views/sheet.jsf is a better solution?

Comment: Agree with @Kukeltje that is exactly what PrimeFaces Extensions Sheet is for.  Being able to be notified of a single cell change or selection.

Comment: @Melloware: Would it be possibe to when you have multiple cells selected and you do a ctrl+c and in an separate text editor do a ctrl-v, you get the text content of all selected cells. Currently you only get the content of the last selected cell.

Comment: Hmm go to the showcase here: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/sheet/basicUsage.jsf  In the first column of "ID" select a range and press CTRL+C.  When I paste into Notepad it copies all the cell values?

Comment: I get this error when I use primefaces extension sheet. I am using primefaces 4.0.   "<pe:sheet> Tag Library supports namespace: http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions, but no tag was defined for name: sheet"

Answer (score 0):

i tried to make it work with datatable since it can get value to cell level.
i use editmode="cell" so i can access to cell level. the inputText is disabled because you don't want the user to edit it.
xhtml:

```
<datatable value"#{yourBean.listValue" var="list" editMode="cell" editable="true"
----and other stuffs----->
    <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{yourBean.selectedCell}"/>
    <p:column headerText="A">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{list.valueA}"/>
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText value="#{list.valueA}" disabled="true"/>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="B">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{list.valueB}"/>
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText value="#{list.valueB}" disabled="true"/>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
----and so on---
</p:datatable>
```

YourBean:

```
String result, A, B;

public void selectedCell(CellEditEvent event) {
    switch(event.getColumn().getHeaderText()) {
        case "A": A= event.getOldValue().toString();
          break;
        case "B": B = event.getOldValue().toString();
          break;
    }
    result = A + B;
}
```

i use switch-case in case you want the result in order. for more info about cell edit in datatable, check [this link](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried to replicate the same and the data table comes up fine for me. But there is no request fired upon clicking any cell. My onCellEdit listener is never called.

Comment: Also, I think for the cellEdit event to work, I need to have the cell edited. It won't work if I just double click the cell. Please correct me if I am wrong. Is there a workaround to this problem ?   @blablabla

Comment: when i tried above code, it called the selectedCell method after the cell edit lost focus. but my code won't let the cell to be edited since i disabled the inputtext. so it works when you select a cell, and then release the focus wether with pressing escape, or click somewhere outside datatable